# I am getting an ValueError while using for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, valueerror

I was practicing for loops and wanted to create a program which asks user input and then convert it to normal and reverse string. For example:-

> Enter a string: python
>
> p    n
>
> y    o
>
> t    h
>
> h    t
>
> o    y
>
> n    p

My code :-

```
inp = input("Enter a string: ")
for row, col in inp[::-1], inp:
    print(row, col)
```

**The error i am getting when typing *"python"* is :-**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    for row, col in inp[::-1], inp:
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**When I type *"py"* then it shows no error:-**

```
y p
p y
```

Comment: Hi! Try `for row, col in zip(inp[::-1], inp)`, that should do the thing

Comment: But how? What does zip does with my code and where i was wrong before buddy? Can you please explain it further?? Well thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've got it, it isn't trying to take one element from each list in turn.

You can wrap your lists in a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and it will do exactly what you want.

```
inp = input("Enter a string: ")
for row, col in zip(inp[::-1], inp):
    print(row, col)
```

The reason it works for `py` is that the string is 2 elements long and you have two variables you assign to (`row`, `col`). It would work for `pyt` if you did `for row, col, z in` for example because the string is 3 characters and you have 3 variables to assign to, and so on and so forth.